# placing an adview below a view when view isn't visible

Tags: android

I have a layout which has an adview under an imageview.In some conditions i am making the imageview invisible which makes my adview to not adjust properly since(android:layout_below attribute i have given to my adview).

`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/previous"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/le"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:onClick="previous"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp" >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ri"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:onClick="next"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp" >
</ImageView>

<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="PUB ID"
        android:layout_below="@+id/next"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:dividerHeight="30.0dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

`

I have used Layout_above attribute for adview to place it above textview since the textview is always visible.But when i do that i got an error saying circular dependencies are not possible in releative layout .Below is the image for better understanding.

[image]

How can i solve this.Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: give complete xml layout. its not clear from above code that you are using LinearLayot or relativeLayout as viewGroup. i guess it should be relativeLayout

Comment: I have used the relative layout for the two imageviews and gave the  id of relative layout to layoutbelow of adview and it solved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you making the `ImageView` invisible? If you are using `imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`, the adView should retain its position.

Comment: imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Change it to `View.INVISIBLE`, because doing so does not remove the `ImageView` from the layout (included in the measure phase), just makes it invisible. And I think that is what you need.